# Sublime text editor 3, Not saving But saving

Tags: javascript, sublimetext3

I spent around 6-7 months, trying to learn code a while ago.
Learning the basics of HTML, CSS, javascript, jQuery and a few others.

I have had a break from it for a while as it was
confusing me & other things in life came up.

Now I'm ready to start again.

I have created a simple HTML file & trying to manipulate it via Javascript.

But each time I try and save the javascript file I am getting the following error (Shown in Sublime).

[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd: ['esvalidate.cmd', '--format=sublime', 'C:\Users\ManDoesNotSubmit\Desktop\Es6NorwichAds\Es6NorwichAdverts.js']]
[dir: C:\Users\ManDoesNotSubmit\Desktop\Es6NorwichAds]
[path: C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\php;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\PHP]
[Finished]

It is confusing me because when I close sublime & re-open the document,
my new changes have been saved but it is still throwing this error....

I have searched forums, Youtube etc.

But all the responses I have found are regarding Python, Build systems & syntax errors.

Not the specific problem I am having.

I am running windows 10, on a cheap laptop.

I have checked the system environment variables & JS is present in both the extensions & path sections, so I cannot understand why it is throwing an error..

I am opening the file directly into sublime, from my desktop so If it could not find the file, it simply would not load the small amount of script I have written..

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hello, Sorry I rejected your edit. To start with it only let me view what you had taken out not, the suggested edit. (Which rendered the question as jibberish). Then It showed both side by side after I had already rejected it can I still Accept the edit or can you accept it from your side...

Comment: Is this stating that It cannot find my file or is it saying it cannot find the file esValidate.cmd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're missing the sublime-jsvalidate `npm` package. [See here](https://github.com/duereg/sublime-jsvalidate)

To be more precise: the error you're getting is about `esvalidate.cmd` not existing, not the file you're trying to save.

Comment: Yes that would make more sense. Thank you.

Comment: If this fixes your problem, please mark it as the correct answer! 